# ga.js Only one request will be sent. Is there any solution

Tags: google-analytics

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','page','format','jpg']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','page','size','100']);
Only one request will be sent. Is there any solution

Comment: You're using _gaq that is deprecated from 2010. Try to use at leat _ga (Universal Analytics) to send hits to the same Property.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. At present, the whole project uses ga.js, so I want to continue to implement it without change